# sass px to em mixin / function for different base sizes on responsive site

Tags: sass

I have been using sass for a while and for ages I have been using the following px to em function for my media queries:

```
$browser-context: 16; // Default

@function em($pixels, $context: $browser-context) {
  @return #{$pixels/$context}em
}
```

However, I am now wanting to set up a different base font size depending on width of screen. SO for instance for mobile sizes

```
$browser-context: 14; // Default
```

and for bigger screens:

```
$browser-context: 16; // Default
```

But Im not sure how to wrap this all up in sass. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that this won't be achievable in SASS without thinking outside the box.

SASS, as you know compiles before getting  sent to the browser, therefore, at that point we have no idea what browser, let alone what screen size. Therefore, media queries are out.

What you could do (I'm theorising here) is:

Set up you em function to produce a series of font sizes specific to different browser widths e.g.

```
@function em780($pixels, $context: $browser-context) {
   @return #{$pixels/$context}em
}
```

and

```
@function em420($pixels, $context: $browser-context) {
   @return #{$pixels/$context}em
}
```

etc.

This should produce the correct em size for each specific screen width. Then, assign those em sizes within a normal media query

```
@media all and (max-width: 420px){
    h1{ font-size: $em420;
}

@media all and (max-width: 780px){
    h1{ font-size: $em780;
}
```

*Does that make any sense ?*

Obviously, don't copy the 'code' I've written here but hopefully the general idea is valid.

Answer (score 0):

This is my mixin:

```
@function em($px, $base: 16px) {
  @return ($px / $base) * 1em;
}
```

use it like font-size: em(24px);. I think it is more clear then just typing values